# KVM: how do I access information on the underlying SSD?

Tags: kvm, ssd, smartctl

I have a small number of VMs in a datacenter, which run on SSDs. I'd like to get some information on the SSD for status reports (ideally, a wear level/percentage used), and to get some idea of whether I should be setting up a swap device.

Is this possible? For everything I've tried, I just run up against the brick wall of the VMware virtual disk.

Things which don't give an answer:

1. `nvme list` - empty
2. `lsblk /dev/sda3` - returns 'Solid state drive', but 'lacks SMART capability'
3. `hdparm /dev/sda3` - nothing useful
4. `lshw -class disk -class storage` - shows a VMware SATA controller, but doesn't seem to have any other useful information
5. `smartctl -a /dev/sda3` - shows a VMware virtual disk, but 'device lacks SMART capability'

**EDIT**

Just to clarify - I'm talking about the guest VM. the guest is running on an unknown host in a datacenter. All I know about the host is that it's running VMware, because the devices I can see in the guest are VMware devices. So, I don't have access to `virsh`, or the KVM setup, or anything else. The guest OS I'm running (Ubuntu 22.04) can clearly detect that it's virtualised, and I'm hoping it can somehow see "through" the guest kernel to find out about the underlying hardware.

Comment: You need to attach the physical disk to the VM first. Here's RedHat's guide: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/virtualization_administration_guide/sect-virtualization-adding_storage_devices_to_guests-adding_hard_drives_and_other_block_devices_to_a_guest

Comment: What's your host?
If you want data from your SSDs, only your host can read those information without injecting said drives to some guest. By doing the latter, you can somwhat inject your very own SSD where the host booted from, but please don't forget to set KVM to only access it as a read-only disk.

Comment: @Peregrino69: I can't do that, unfortunately - see the edit above

Comment: @X.LINK: I don't have any access to the host, so I guess this isn't gonig to be possible.

Comment: And it shouldn't be - for very obvious security reasons.

Comment: @QF0 If you can't access the host by any means (like remotely, etc), then there's nothing that can be done. A virtual machine by definition, is motly isolated from the host.

If you can remotely access it with VSPhere (which can limit access for users to some parts of the host), then it might be possible. Or it'll even give you the information right away if you have the correct rights. No security risks involved at all unless the sysadmin didn't do his homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't be possible. The whole point of renting you VM resources is that you stay within the confines of that VM and not interfere not get any information about other customers' VMs.

So, unless you rented a bare metal server where you do get access to these kind of things, no sane cloud provider could give you this kind of access.

You said that your VMs run in a datacenter. Now that probably means that your VMs are but a small piece of the storage used there. Typically, there will not be a single SSD that underlies your VM: that would both be expensive and unreliable. Instead, your virtual disks will be provided by some block device emulation layer, which distributes your data onto many SSDs, and adds error-correction information as well.

That way, when one of the physical storage media fail (and once you put a couple hundred in a datacenter, the chance that one fails is pretty pretty large), there's no interruption or loss of data, as the storage system can seamlessly continue to operate with one device less in the backing storage, thanks to the error correction. At the same time, whilst adding that one-falls-that's-OK safety, you don't have to buy two SSDs whenever you attach one SSD to a VM - a specific percentage of overall storage is enough.

Thus, neither could you theoretically be allowed to directly read information from the underlying devices (due to the security implications of that), nor is it likely that this one SSD really exists - you're writing on a virtual block device that is probably striped across a whole lot of SSDs in a storage cluster.

Comment: I like your point about the datacenter. However, I do wonder if the cheaper VPS providers (or all of them?) just attach a single cheap SSD drive, then sell 50 VMs per motherboard, and hope for the best. I don't buy the security issue, though. SMART attributes just give you information on disk reliability. You'd have to be a damn good hacker to turn that into usable information about other VMs. But, maybe it's possible...

Comment: nah, space in a datacenter is too expensive to make money at that tiny scale. And nope, it really does matter when you can figure how much i/o your competition does – cloud customers are very particular about leaking data to other customers, for good reason. These scenarios are not very hypothetical .